# SurfaceView of type PUSH_BUFFERS

Tags: android, drawing, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I have some experience with the `SurfaceView`. To prevent unneeded redrawing, I always use a countdown variable which tells the thread how often the view should be drawn.

```
countdown > 0 : draw ? doNothing
```

However I was thinking about changing that to use a "push surface". So just push a buffer to the surface and show that instead of setting a countdown variable everywhere in my project.

My problem is that I can't find a good tutorial/resource where the usage is described. Currently I have something like this:

```
// panel is the SurfaceView
c = panel.getHolder().lockCanvas(null);
synchronized (panel.getHolder()) {
    panel.updatePhysics();
    panel.onDraw(c);
}
panel.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

I have no idea on how to get the canvas to draw on when I can't use `lockCanvas()` as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is obsolete after making the surface types deprecated. So it isn't used anymore...

Comment: Depends. If you're trying to use the CameraPreview, as in the SDK 7 samples, `SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS` is required. If you fail to set this type, the preview won't work. So there must be an interpretation somewhere in the camera API, even though the types are marked deprecated.